# How can I align text to the top and the bottom of the same div css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align one line of text to the top of an image on also to the bottom of an image.

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aoVU0IQ2lJw0MC9gP86h?p=preview)

```
******  Name
******
******  More Info


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/102031900129645/picture?type=square&redirect=true&width=100&height=100">
    <span>John Smith</span>
    <br>
    <span>10 friends</span>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On the image or above and below image, or besides it top and bottom?

Comment: the image is on the left, the content would be on the right and aligned with the top and bottom of the image @OriDrori

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.col-md-4 {
    position: relative;
}

.col-md-4 span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.col-md-4 span:last-child {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Working **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HQRU3NmwDxRdJkzPHP6h?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Just write your spans above the image.
2. Give the parent div position:
   relative.
3. Give the spans position: absolute with top:0, bottom:0 (as
   required).

```css
.col-md-4 {
    position: relative;
}

.col-md-4 .name {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.col-md-4 .info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <span class="name">John Smith</span>
      <span class="info">10 friends</span>  
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/102031900129645/picture?type=square&redirect=true&width=100&height=100" />
  </div>
</div>
```